# How to convert floating point to binary on the command line?

Tags: shell, command-line, floating-point, binary-data

I'd like a simple way to convert a float string on the command line to a binary float.

For example:

```
$ echo "1.23" > file.bin
```

Except with the output as a 4 byte IEEE float

I'd expect the result of

```
$ od -f -An file.bin
1.23
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope that there is a more compact way of doing this but, if not, try:

**Python 2:**

```
$ python -c "import sys,struct; sys.stdout.write(struct.pack('f', float(sys.argv[-1])))" 1.23 >file.bin
$ od -f -An file.bin
            1.23
```

**Python 3:**

```
$ python3 -c "import sys,struct; sys.stdout.buffer.write(struct.pack('f', float(sys.argv[-1])))" 1.23 >file3.bin
$ od -f -An file3.bin
            1.23
```

(Hat tip: [Mark Dickinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270986/mark-dickinson))

#### How it works

- `import sys,struct`

  Tells python to import the sys and struct modules.
- `sys.stdout.write(struct.pack('f', float(sys.argv[-1])))`

  Tells python to take the last argument on the command line, `sys.argv[-1])` and, use `float` to convert it to a float number, and use `struct.pack` to convert the float to a bit string, and finally use `sys.stdout.write` to send the bytes to stdout.

Comment: I'm starting to think Python really isn't well suited for one liners.

Comment: This won't work with Python 3, where `sys.stdout.write` expects Unicode text rather than bytes. Replacing `sys.stdout` with `sys.stdout.buffer` might do it.

Comment: @MarkDickinson You are right.  Thanks!  Answer updated with `sys.stdout.buffer.write` for python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Similar, but less verbose, approach using Perl:

```
$ perl -e 'print pack("f", $ARGV[0])' 1.23 > file.bin
```